# There is an issue with my triangle triples program

Tags: c++

My program is supposed to list all right triangle triples between 1-500. It should not repeat the same triangles. For example 3, 4, 5 is the same as 4, 3, 5 and only the first one should be displayed. I also am supposed to have a counter at the end of the program which displays how many triangles were found. So far this is what I have. It is currently not displaying the correct amount of triangles and the counter is not working correctly. Thanks

```
// Naming

int counter;

// For loops and nested for loops

{
       // Makes sure side A starts at 1 and is less than 500
for (int a = 1; a <= 500; a++)
{
       // Makes sure side B starts at 1 and is less than 500
    for (int b = 1; b <= 500; b++)
    {
       // Makes sure side C starts at 1 and us kess than 500
        for (int c = 1; c <= 500; c++)
        {
       // If A squared + B squared = C squared and C squared, A, and B --> 
       // are all less than or equal to 500 then display the answer
            if ((a*a)+(b*b) == c*c & a & b <= 500) {
            // This is my counter I cannot seem to get it to work properly
            // More info about counter at bottom
            counter++;
                cout << a << ", " << b << ", " << c << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
}

cout << endl;
// Displaying counter
cout << counter << endl << endl ;

system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Too many loops: If you know `a` and `b`, you can calculate `c`.

Answer (score 1):

The following line will not do what you expect:

```
// If A squared + B squared = C squared and C squared, A, and B --> 
// are all less than or equal to 500 then display the answer
    if ((a*a)+(b*b) == c*c & a & b <= 500) {
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Chang it to:

```
if ((a*a)+(b*b) == c*c && a <= 500 && b <= 500) {
```

ps: As further commented by @Code-Apprentice, `a <= 500 && b <= 500` are already guaranteed by the `for`-loop, thus it can be simplified to:

```
if ((a*a)+(b*b) == c*c) {
```

Comment: Note that the conditions that `a <= 500` and `b <= 500` are redundant because this is guaranteed by the for loop counters.

Answer (score 1):

Force your triples to be sorted before creating them. The hypotenuse will always be last, and the shortest leg will always be first. (We will not need to worry about (a, a, b), since such integral combinations won't exist.

So for a solution triple (a,b,c), it should always be true that a < b < c, and a > 0, b > 0, c > 0.

Easy. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely counting some triples twice. If you check your output, you will definitely see that "3, 4, 5" is repeated 6 times. In fact, **every** triple will be repeated 6 times. This suggests that a quick fix is to divide your counter by 6.

Alternatively, you can make sure that you don't repeat any triples by using the outer loops to define the starting point for the inner loops:

```
for (int a = 1; a <= 500; a++)
{
    // Makes sure side B starts at 1 and is less than 500
    for (int b = a + 1; b <= 500; b++)
    {
       // Makes sure side C starts at 1 and us kess than 500
        for (int c = b + 1; c <= 500; c++)
```

p.s. Also, the error in your `if` condition guarantees that **every** combination of numbers is counted so the output is `625000000`. Be sure to fix this as described in [herohuyongtao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26269668/1440565).

Comment: Good... but no loop is needed to find `c`, just use sqrt.

Comment: @BenVoigt That is certainly a decent optimization once the OP gets a correct solution to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

The counter isn't initialized to 0. Where is your logic to skip like triangles?